# X11 forwarding via "ssh -X username@hostname" is slow, but fast using "nxclient"

Tags: ssh, nx, x11-forwarding

As mentioned, when I do X11 forwarding using basic `ssh -X username@hostname` it's quite sluggish. But interestingly, when I use `nxclient`, it's *significantly* faster.

I'd rather use `ssh` instead of `nxclient`, due to various reasons.

I've tried turning on compression and setting ciphers, (i.e. `ssh -X -C -c blowfish-cbc,arcfour username@hostname`) but it's still pretty sluggish.

Why is that? How do I speed up `ssh` X11 forwarding to be up to par with `nxclient`?

Comment: The whole point of [nx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology) is to speed things up....

Comment: @demure Are you saying there's no way basic `ssh -X` could be up to par with `nxclient`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The NoMachine NX library is basically a derivative of DXPC.
It is stated in wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology
 "The NX scheme was derived from that of DXPC – the Differential X Protocol Compressor project".

So while `ssh -C -X` simply compresses whatever you feed it with (in your case, an X session), NX goes the extra mile to NOT send the 'unchanged' bits of information that it has already sent, thus the 'differential' term. Once what needs to be sent has been decided, nx will actually use ssh (or rather an nx derivative of ssh, `nxssh` to transmit session information).

So there is no way that the `ssh -X -C` will be as efficient as setting up an nx session. (nxclient is only one end of the deal btw, you will need the corresponding nxserver - i.e you cannot just replace the nxclient with ssh -X).

EDIT (as per requested):
As far as speeding up the `ssh`, I can only go as far as saying that using compressiong `-C` generally helps. This is backed up in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21016/how-to-speed-up-x-over-ssh-on-a-slow-network-connection) question.

Perhaps one can also consider switching to very lightweight desktop environments, such as `xfce` or even simpler like `fluxbox`. Of course this will only help with window drawing operations rather than with speeding up the content in the windows but still.

Comment: This doesn't answer the user's question.  He I don't see an indication of him trying to replace `ssh -X` with `nxclient`.  He's asking as well as I would like to know, how to speed up `ssh -X`.  Can you add something related to this to your answer, or give the steps for speeding up `ssh -X` in a reply to this comment if it's possible?  What could be done on both the server and client to have the maximum speed that can be delivered by from an `Ubuntu to Ubuntu` `ssh` GUI connection?